# Is there a full disk encyption software that shows different content depending on what password has beeen used?

Tags: disk-encryption, software

I'm searching for a 256-bit full disk encryption software that allows me to access different content on the same disk with different passwords. Like: Password A opens partition 1, password B opens partition 2, password C opens both partitions. Same principle with folders would also be sufficient. Is there a software like this?

Comment: Welcome to Security Stack Exchange! Unfortunately product recommendation is off-topic here. You may be able to get help on [SoftwareRecs.Se]; please do read their question guidelines before posting there.

Comment: This question was almost fine if it was worded differently, perhaps like, "Would it be possible to have FDE software that ..." instead of asking if it exists and for a specific product. The answer to this wording of the question would be, yes, it should be possible to implement, but every time you create multiple keys to unlock the same thing, you are decreasing security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TrueCrypt** had a Plausible Deniabiliy feature that allowed a hidden encrypted volume inside another encrypted volume. It is not maintained anymore, but you can check **CipherShed** and **VeraCrypt** which are forks of the original project.

Comment: Using TrueCrypt is not secure as it may contain unfixed security issues, migrate from truecrypt to Bitlocker, according to home page:http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Uh, with BitLocker being developed by an US company under US law, offering stunning protection with an unknown, undocumented implementation, a TPM module that you can't look inside, and a startup PIN that's hard limited to 68-bit strength, this is alltogether of course a lot more secure than Truecrypt which _might_ possibly contain unfixed unknown security issues (... or using a more recent, maintained fork).

Comment: @Ali: That's why I mentioned CipherShed and VeraCrypt. TrueCrypt is an abandoned project and should not be used anymore.

Comment: @Damon "unknown, undocumented implementation" - BitLocker's crypto design is fully documented. [Here's a starting point](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc162804.aspx). [Here's some more](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.bitlocker.aspx). You also don't need to use the TPM - mine's deactivated and I run BitLocker in passphrase mode - it's entirely optional to use the TPM. The "startup pin" is also not limited to 68-bit strength - I can't find any reference to this anywhere and would like to know where you found it.

Comment: @Damon I would also point out that BitLocker has been reviewed by plenty of people in the security community. Just because there's no code available doesn't mean people aren't disassembling and looking at things. The full NT6.1 code is also available under shared license, which a fair number of organisations have access to.

Comment: @Polynomial: The first TN article you linked to explicitly states that the entropy of the PIN is "limited" (although it doesn't go into detail) and talks of implementation-defined brute force mitigation techniques (which are, of course, entirely irrelevant in a lab attack). The 68 bit strengt can be calculated from the range of allowed symbols and the upper limit on length.

Comment: @Damon The basic PIN in TPM mode is a numeric identifier, and you're right that its entropy is relatively low - 68 bits or so at best. In [enhanced PIN mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee449438%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) with a TPM, you can use 20 7-bit ASCII characters, which is more like 132 bits of entropy. Keep in mind that the TPM actively rate-limits you so brute force against it should not be possible.

Comment: @Damon Also, you can just turn off the TPM and use BitLocker in passphrase mode, which means you (a) don't have to rely on the TPM, and (b) can use a passphrase of any number of 7-bit ASCII characters (I don't think there's a limit). My passphrase easily breaches 200 bits according to KeePass' estimation, and we have some automatic-entry ones at work that I guarantee are in excess of 500 bits.

Comment: Of course, if it works the way it's advertised, "plausible deniability" also means that you cannot prove that no such separate container exists. Which in some jurisdictions means you can be put in jail until you give up the passphrase that you don't have, for the data that doesn't exist.